# React Random images suffle

Tags: reactjs

I doing a form that is working fine but when I want to shuffle images randomly continuously it shows error. I can do it index but after it reaches to end it not shuffle back from 0, could anyone check what is the problem in my code. Thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/course-form-f1j1k?file=/src/Lists.js
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go with index, here is the simple solution

```
src={images[index%6]}
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/course-form-0tftn?file=/src/Lists.js) (With index)

---

To get random images, you can do something like this,

App.js

```
const [random, setRandom] = useState([]);
const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);

const submitBtn = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRandom([...random, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]);
    setLists([...lists, final]);
};

const remove = index => {
    let removeRandom = random.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
    setRandom(removeRandom);
    let removeList = lists.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
    setLists(removeList);
};
```

Lists.js

```
<img src={images[random[index]]} className="img-fluid" alt="" />
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/course-form-u6i0d?file=/src/App.js)** (with random)

---

**Here is the another much more clean way of doing :** **[WORKING DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/course-form-jvem9?file=/src/Lists.js)**.

Comment: Thanks, Vivek... its working but remove button not remove the images link updated https://codesandbox.io/s/course-form-f1j1k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Rahul, There are multiple ways you can solve this issue, it purely depends on how you want to implement.